# Use custom redirect match redirects together with RewriteRule in Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect all URLs from `domain1` to `domain2` maintaining the same links.

I use a `RewriteRule` for this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But if I want to make a custom redirect that would override this `RewriteRule`, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Please add an example for your custom redirect, i.e. which requests you (don't) want to redirect.

Comment: "Use custom redirect match redirects" - do you mean to use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch`?

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule and RewriteCond e.g. are sensitive to order so you just need to place a new RewriteRule above your catchall with a Last [L] flag

```
RewriteRule "^(SOME REGEX)" "/some-url" [R=301,L]
```

**Resources**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteRule